# Is there any Undo feature for changes in tags or appearance of text in Text widget tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

`.edit_undo()` function is used for reversing the insertion or deletion of text in Text widget tkinter.

Is there any function that I can use to undo the setting of tags onto a certain range of text?

Comment: Setting of tags? Can you clarify what you mean? Your question is hard to understand, at least for me.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is nothing built-in to handle that. The [tk documentation](http://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TkCmd/text.htm#M65) explicitly states that the undo mechanism only applies to inserts and deletes:

> The text widget has an unlimited undo and redo mechanism (when the -undo widget option is true) which records every insert and delete action on a stack.

There is no mention at all about anything else being handled by the undo/redo mechanism. If you have the need to undo/redo the application of tags, you will have to write the code to manage that yourself.